# python install from python script causes reboot

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-install

I have a python script where I am doing unattended installs of a bunch of apps. One of the apps itself installs specific python version 2.6-32bit, pywin32 and some other packages, then fixes the install back to 2.7. When I run this app's unattended install from python script, the python2.7 installer reports a bunch of files "c:\python27\xxx held in use"  blah blah "scheduling reboot operation...Must reboot to complete operation". Makes sense but I don't want it to reboot, and I want to run it from within my python script.

The python msi installer is running with /norestart. Doesn't seem to help.

I have ability to edit the Apps installer source code (how it runs the python msi install)

Answer (score 0):

Package your script with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) so that it runs with a private copy of Python, rather than with `C:\python27`.